# Can we connect Looker to Google Sheets Directly

Tags: google-sheets, connection, looker

I want to know if there is any update in latest looker version about connecting looker to google sheet directly? if yes then can someone please help me with the steps to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to connect Google Sheet directly to your database.

Here's an example to Looker's internal use case:

https://help.looker.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023860613-How-to-use-Google-Spreadsheets-to-Input-Data-into-Looker

The example is based on MySQL, if you are connected to BigQuery - hosting a temporary table is also a fine option.

Answer (score -1):

One simple way to connect Google Sheets directly to the Looker Studio.

please follow these steps which I have mentioned below.

1. generate a new page to create a chart
2. after that click on the add data option.
3. select a google sheet extension(For sheet only)
4. after selecting whatever sheet you use for the charts.

[image]

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: NOTE: This question is about Looker, not Looker Studio.